# UniGrid Binding

Tags: sql, binding, kentico, unigrid

I am new to kentico cms.I am working on existing kentico project.In that one unigrid used for displaying record from database and for binding unigrid they were using "query" property of unigrid.But am not able to find this query's "SQL" any where in admin interface or in code it self.Can anyone help me please to find the solution.

Note:I am Using Kentico 9 version.

Comment: Please provide what the value of the "query" property is set to.  This will help find where the actual query is in the Kentico UI.

Answer (score 2):

Some basic queries, such as "selectall", "update", etc. are auto-generated.

The easiest way to see the actual query along with its name is to enable [SQL debug](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/managing-sites/configuring-settings-for-sites/settings-system/settings-debug#Settings-Debug-SQLqueries) and navigate to the page with the UniGrid.

That way, you'll see the text and codename of the query.

[image: SQL DEBUG]

If you'll need to customize the query, you can copy the query text, adjust it, and save it as a new [custom query](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/loading-data-using-custom-queries).

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote display date from database, are you referring to data stored the custom tables module ?

If so you have to open the custom tables modules and there is a Queries link on the left nav that has all queries used with this table